# Extracting dynamic content Web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I am aware that XMLHTTP only fetches the initial page source, it won't perform any dynamic updates. I don't want to try automating IE as its too slow.

I have attached the code below. I want to extract the volume of this stock both in BSE and NSE.
But NSE volume can be extracted only upon clicking "View NSE".
I get error while extracting the NSE volume as

> "Object variable not set"

Please help me out with a solution and I am new to XHR, JSON etc...

```
Sub PV_Extract()

    Dim wpage As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim hdoc As New HTMLDocument


        URL = "https://money.rediff.com/companies/Asian-Paints-Ltd/11580001"
        wpage.Open "GET", URL, False
        wpage.send

        While wpage.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set hdoc = New HTMLDocument

        hdoc.body.innerHTML = wpage.responseText

        Set today_tab_bse = hdoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1)
        Set today_tab_nse = hdoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(1).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1)

        vol_1 = today_tab_bse.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
        vol_2 = today_tab_nse.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText

End Sub
```

Comment: You are going to have problems trying to automate any financial websites. They do not want you doing that, so they make it has hard as possible. Even if you can get something working, they will most likely change something the next day that will make it no longer work.

Comment: I experience it, but I still want to further my learning by getting over these obstacles.

Comment: ok - good luck :)

Comment: Is this an excel issue?

Comment: If someone wants to solve a task in Excel, I think it is an Excel issue. Excel is often a good choice for web scraping because the values obtained can be processed immediately in the tables.

Comment: Why not use a different source? For example, alphavantage.co has an API which provides access to those stocks. You need to prepend the exchange to the symbol so you would use `BSE:ASIANPAINT` or `NSE:ASIANPAINT`, the daily series, and retrieve the info you need perhaps more easily than web-scraping.  You will need to learn about JSON though.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'll explore that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always declare all variables. You can scrape the elements by their ids.

```
Sub PV_Extract()

Dim wpage As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim url As String
Dim hdoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim today_tab_bse As Object
Dim today_tab_nse As Object
Dim vol_1 As String
Dim vol_2 As String

  url = "https://money.rediff.com/companies/Asian-Paints-Ltd/11580001"
  wpage.Open "GET", url, False
  wpage.send
  Set hdoc = New HTMLDocument
  hdoc.body.innerHTML = wpage.responseText

  Set today_tab_bse = hdoc.getElementByID("for_BSE")
  Set today_tab_nse = hdoc.getElementByID("for_NSE")

  vol_1 = today_tab_bse.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
  vol_2 = today_tab_nse.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText

  MsgBox "BSE: " & vol_1 & Chr(13) & "NSE: " & vol_2
End Sub
```

## Edit: Get values for BSE and NSE

```
Sub PV_Extract()

Dim wpage As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim url As String
Dim hdoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim vol_1 As String
Dim vol_2 As String

  url = "https://money.rediff.com/companies/Asian-Paints-Ltd/11580001"
  wpage.Open "GET", url, False
  wpage.send
  Set hdoc = New HTMLDocument
  hdoc.body.innerHTML = wpage.responseText

  vol_1 = hdoc.getElementByID("ltpid").innerText
  vol_2 = hdoc.getElementByID("ltpid_nse").innerText

  MsgBox "BSE: " & vol_1 & Chr(13) & "NSE: " & vol_2
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. But this does not add up both the volumes as XML is not picking the dynamic data.

Comment: I second what you wrote about excel- "Excel is often a good choice for web scraping because the values obtained can be processed immediately in the tables."

Comment: @MathInquiry I have supplemented my answer with a second macro that provides the data you requested.